# Evaluating $\sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was studying for some quizzes when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> If the ith Fibonacci number is denoted by $f_i$, calculate $\sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i}$

**My work**

The Fibonacci sequence looks like this: $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55......$

The formula to get the ith term of a Fibonacci sequence is $ith \space term = \frac{a^i + b^i}{a+b}$, where $a = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $b = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Looking at the given formula above....it becomes...

$$ \sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i} = f_{2(3)} +f_{2(4)} + f_{2(5)}$$
$$ \sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i} = f_6 +f_8 + f_{10} $$

Getting now the 6th, 8th and 10th term of the Fibonacci sequence:

$$6th \space term = \frac{a^6 + b^6}{a+b} = 18$$
$$8th \space term = \frac{a^8 + b^8}{a+b} = 47$$
$$10th \space term = \frac{a^{10} + b^{10}}{a+b} = 123$$

Then....

$$ \sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i} = f_{2(3)} +f_{2(4)} + f_{2(5)}$$
$$ \sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i} = f_6 +f_8 + f_{10} $$
$$ \sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i} = 18 + 47 + 123 = 188$$

The problem is that my answer wasn't in the choices, then I don't know where I screwed up.

How to properly get $\sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i}$

The choices were $$55, \space 178, \space 89, \space 84$$

Comment: Are you sure about the problem statement ? This is just $F_6+F_8+F_{10}$, which can even be computed mentally. Better to tell us what the choices were.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It was my first time encountering that problem...so it thought it might be difficult......The notation was intimidating......plus...I often get thrown out if I ever encounter more genuinely-difficult versions of the above problem.....I just want to make  sure that my train of logic is correct..........hehehehe.....

Comment: You don't answer my questions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes...that's how it was written....I discovered that question while helping a friend on his review classes......The choices were $55, 178, 89, 84$

Answer (score 1):

The Fibonacci's first term is variously set to be either $0$ or $1$. Clearly, this question is adopting the latter convention (whereas you assumed the former), giving:

$f_6 = 8, f_8 = 21, f_{10} = 55$ and the required sum is $84$.

As another answer-giver stated, don't overcomplicate things.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=3}^5 f_{2i} = f_6 + f_8 + f_{10} = 8+21+55 = 84$$

It's the last option. You're complicating everything.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Just plug in the numbers you know: $8 + 21 +55 =?$

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other answers, those numbers are small enough that you can evaluate them directly. After all, you have listed them earlier.

As for the mistake.

$$f_i = \frac{a^i\color{red}{-}b^i}{a\color{red}{-}b}=\frac{a^i-b^i}{\sqrt{5}}$$